# Keep html when filtering jquery response from .ajax

Tags: jquery, html, filter, response

I am calling a page that returns data like:

```
<div id="class">
    <option>Value</option>
    <option>Value</option>
</div>

<div id="type">
    <option>Value</option>
    <option>Value</option>
</div>
```

I am trying to filter the data so that I can cycle through each one and insert the option values into the correct section drop down list for them.  I even extended the data so that I could try .find() on it, and made it look like:

```
<div id="class">
    <div class="options">
        <option>Value</option>
        <option>Value</option>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="type">
    <div class="options">
        <option>Value</option>
        <option>Value</option>
    </div>
</div>
```

However, it still does not work.  I only get the text output, and not the html elements.  So my question is, how do I keep the actual html elements when I use the .filter() command?  My current code is below.

```
$.ajax({  
    type: "POST", 
    url: "searchFunctions.php",
    data: dataString,
    success: function(data) {
        // Create jquery object from the response html
        var $response=$(data);

        // Change styles for children
        $response.filter('div').each(function(){
            $("#"+$(this).attr("id")).html($(this).find(".options"));
        });
    }
});
```

Please note, I did try .text() and .html() at the end of $(this).find(".options") with no luck.  It still only returned the value portion.  But it's weird.  When I used $(this).html() (no .find(".options.")), I could see the  tags, but still not the  tags...

Thanks in advance.

> Yeah, never even thought about the fact that the browser would drop the option tags due to no select tag...

Comment: How (why?) are you putting `<option>` tags inside of `<div>` tags?

Comment: I'm going to guess that this might be due to the fact that a `div` can't contain `option` in valid HTML. Have you tried wrapping the options in a `select` instead of a `div`?

Comment: Because I have multiple dropdowns, and needed a way to differentiate what options were for which dropdown.  Then, the filter parses the returned data by the div tags, and for each id of the main div tags, it knows which dropdown the options are associated with.  The div tags and option tags are the only things being output on the page the jquery is calling.

Comment: @nrabinowitz Yes, using the <select> tags instead of <div> tags worked, and using .html()  Thanks.  Write up an answer and I'll mark it as correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because a `div` element can't contain an `option` element in valid HTML. This will work if you wrap the options in a `select` rather than a `div`:

```
<select id="type">
    <option>Value</option>
    <option>Value</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Thanks again.  Didn't even think about that when I wrote it.

Answer (score 2):

Have you considered returning a JSON string rather than html code in your ajax response? This would make it easier to parse and the amount of data being sent from server would be smaller.

The JSON response would look like:

```
'{"class":["option1", "option2"], "type": ["option1", "option2", "option3"]}'
```

Then use the parseJSON method to get your response into an object. See the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bxpLg/2/) for working example

Comment: No, but I don't know JSON too well.  Only had to use it once in a phone app.  Though I need to learn it better, I'd rather stay away from it for now.  I appreciate the idea, though.

Comment: Ok I would definitely look into it. I updated the jsfiddle link in my post to show how to put the options in the select boxes. For more info on JSON check out [json.org](http://www.json.org/), its pretty easy to learn!